# Accepting a different field in POST in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If I have the following Dango model and Django REST serializer:

```py
# model
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

# serializer
class AttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    code = serializers.CharField()
    value = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Attribute
        fields = ('name', 'code', 'value', 'group')
```

Is it possible to accept a different field during the `PUT` or `POST` to update the model? for example, could it accept `attribute_value` and use that to update the `value` field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `to_internal_value` function read more on [Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer):

> Override this to support deserialization, for write operations.

You can override it like this:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    if data.get('attribute_value'):
        data['value'] = data.pop('attribute_value')
    data = super().to_internal_value(data)
    return data
```